# Differential equation question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have already asked for help on this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344142/solving-a-differential-equation-substitution-has-been-recommended), but I did not fully explain the question and therefore didn't get the answer I was looking for. I am struggling with part aii. Specifically where I have to solve:

$$z'=\frac{-2y_0^2(x_0+t)}{z}+3y_0$$

[The Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liN82.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Coming back to [the question itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liN82.jpg), one looks for a solution 
$$
u:(x,y)\mapsto u(x,y)=z(2xy,x^2+y^2),
$$ 
for some function $z:(t,s)\mapsto z(t,s)$ to be determined. Now, $u_x=2yz_t+2xz_s$ and $u_y=2xz_t+2yz_s$ hence the system of equations involving $u_x$ and $u_y$ can be rewritten as
$$
z_t+\frac{t}z-c=2\frac{x}yz_s=2\frac{y}xz_s,\qquad c=\frac32.
$$
On the open set $x\ne y$, this means that $z_s=0$, hence $z(t,s)$ depends on $t$ only and solves the ODE 
$$
z_t+\frac{t}z=c.
$$
Following the hint, assume that $z(t,s)=tv(t)$, then $z_t=tv'+v$ hence the ODE is equivalent to $tv'+v+\frac1v=c$, which is equivalent to the separable ODE
$$
\frac{v'}{v+\frac1v-c}=-\frac1t.
$$
Can you take it from here?